# Find number of ordered pairs

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find the number of ordered pairs $(p , q)$ such that $p , q $ are both prime numbers less than 50 , and $pq$+1 is divisible by 12

Edit :
What i have done is i have written down all the primes below 50 congruent to modulo 12 .
For example : 11 $ \equiv$ -3 $(mod 12)$

Comment: What have you tried in solving the question? Please include that below your question body (as an edit).

Comment: you could do this in excel by hand -- what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @gt6989b Or just by hand, without excel ...

Comment: @Peter how? There are going to be a lot of combinations

Comment: We have $15$ primes below $50$, making $105$ pairs. Moreover $2$ and $3$ can be omitted because a number of the form $2k+1$ is odd and a number of the form $3k+1$ not disivisble by $3$. So, the number of pairs decreases to $78$. With a bit patience, well feasible by hand.

Comment: Remark : The case $p=q$ can be omitted as well, because $p^2+1$ is never disivible by $3$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Note that $p,q$ cannot be 2 or 3. Then $p,q \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{6}$.

Note that 
$$(6k+1)(6n+1) \equiv 6(k+n)+1 \not\equiv -1 \pmod{12} \\
(6k-1)(6n-1) \equiv -6(k+n)+1 \not\equiv -1 \pmod{12} $$

Therefore, the only posibility left is
$$(6k+1)(6n-1) \equiv 6(n-k)-1 \pmod{12} $$
which is $\equiv -1 \pmod{12}$ if and only if $k-n$ is even.

Comment: How did you get that $(6k+1)(6n+1)≡6(k+n)+1\not\equiv−1$ (mod12)?

Comment: @mampuuu Just open the brackets and use the fact that $36 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$. For the last non-equality, note that $6(k+n) \equiv 0,6 \pmod{12}$, depending if $k+n$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly we need both $p$ and $q$ to be coprime to $12$, so we cannot have $p$ or $q$ equal to either $2$ or $3$.

This means that $\{p,q\}\in\{1,5,7,11\}\bmod 12$. We can quickly calculate the products $\bmod 12$ across this set:

\begin{array}{l|cc}
p\ \backslash\ q & 1 & 5 & 7 &  11 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 5 & 7 &  11 \\
5 & 5 & 1 & 11 &  7 \\
7 & 7 & 11 & 1 &  5 \\
11 & 11 & 7 & 5 &  1 \\
\end{array}

We are looking for $p,q$ pairs that give $11\equiv -1 \bmod 12$ in the above table so that $12\mid pq{+}1$. So we would select the pairs from the different residue class sets appropriately, which gives a way to calculate how many options in total.

For example, the set of primes in range $\equiv 1 \bmod 12$ (call this $S_1$) consists of just $\{13,37\}$. This gives us $|S_1|=2$ and similarly $|S_5|=4,$ $|S_7|=4,$ and $|S_{11}|=3$. Thus we will have $2\cdot 3  + 4\cdot 4  + 4\cdot 4  + 3\cdot 2  = 2\cdot 6+2\cdot 16= \fbox{44 }$ ordered pair solutions.

Comment: But I guess 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: No it isn't; you're looking (in that case) for the prime numbers that fit $p\equiv 1 \bmod 12$. Similarly in the other cases you're looking for the sets of prime numbers $\equiv 5,7,11 \bmod 12$. Example added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers are in very small range, I wrote a simple Python script for it. Takes $ < 1 $ second.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(x**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

ans = 0
for p in range(2, 50):
    if is_prime(p):
        for q in range(2, 50):
            if is_prime(q):
                    ans += (p*q + 1) % 12 == 0
print(ans)
```

The answer:

> 44